# Ember pre-render: timed out while initializing

Tags: ember.js, prerender

I am trying to create a pre-render server for my ember app.

I installed `ember-prerender` (https://github.com/zipfworks/ember-prerender), used the initializers provided in the /example, deployed it on one of my servers.

But when I try to launch it:

```
Restarting renderer, timed out while initializing
```

This is the case even if I change engine (I tried with Phantom and jsdom).

My best guess is that the `XContentReady` event is never fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was indeed `XContentReady` not firering that was causing the problem.
I didn't add the mixin that was triggering the event:

mixins/ember-prerender.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  willComplete: function() {
    Ember.RSVP.resolve();
  },
  actions: {
    didTransition: function() {
      this._super();

      var promises = [];
      var currentHandlerInfos = this.router.get('router.currentHandlerInfos');
      for (var i = 0; i < currentHandlerInfos.length; i++) {
        if (currentHandlerInfos[i].handler.willComplete) {
          promises.push(currentHandlerInfos[i].handler.willComplete());
        }
      }

  Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(window.prerenderReady); //<-- FIRERING HERE
}
}
});
```