# Ember pre-render: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'u.bind(e)')

Tags: ember.js, prerender

I am trying to create a pre-render server for my ember app.

I installed `ember-prerender` (https://github.com/zipfworks/ember-prerender), used the initializers provided in the /example, deployed it on one of my servers.

But when I try to launch it:

```
[Renderer 0] Engine starting up (phantom)
[Renderer 0] Restarting rendering engine in 25000 seconds after it failed
             with error: Phantom encountered an error: TypeError: 
             'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'u.bind(e)')
```

I'm unsure where to look. I tried:

- Deleting all third-party SDK (Facebook, Google Analytics)
- Logging different parts of the code (the event `XContentReady` seems to be fired)
- Launching with the engine `jsdom` instead of `phantom` (gives: `[Renderer 0] Restarting renderer, timed out while initializing`)
- Trying in production

I don't know where too look at now. The worse part is that I had it working a few days ago (see: [Ember pre-render: timed out while initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547516/ember-pre-render-timed-out-while-initializing))

EDIT:

I don't think that the problem has anything to do with the code, since I did a hard reset to a version that used to work.

- Maybe some version changed (bower, npm, phantom)? I tried to update bower to 1.6, no success.
- Maybe I have new dependencies that cause the problem? I don't see exactly how though

EDIT2: I started fresh on a new server, now I get Phantom crashing with this error message:

```
[Renderer 0] Restarting rendering engine in 25000 seconds
after it failed with error: Erroneous exit code: null SIGSEGV
```

If I use JSDOM I still get the `Restarting renderer, timed out while initializing`

EDIT 3: I tried to include a polyfill in my app. Using:

- github.com/es-shims/es5-shim
- then as an addon: github.com/pixelhandler/ember-cli-es5-shim

With no success

EDIT 4: I'm having the same error with a brand new project, containing only ember-prerender, so I'm thinking it's either linked to my particular build (`version: 1.13.13, node: 0.12.3, npm: 2.14.10, os: linux x64`), or my computer packages/configuration.

Comment: "I don't think that the problem has anything to do with the code" - can you try running that on clean new ember app to confirm?

Comment: When you say "new ember app, do you mean that the endpoint "appUrl" should be different that what it is now? (`http://www.example.com/`), or that the ember app that is running the pre-render should be new (but then why?)

Comment: If you could run `ember new whatever` and test it on that new application. Then if it works you could step by step add your code from parent application to narrow down issue if you encounter one, or to completely port your application and run it without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with jsdom, but `Function.prototype.bind` is not supported with phantomjs@1.9 and lower. Have you tried phantomjs@2.0?

Comment: The problem is that Phantom's version is defined by ember-prerender , so I don't get to change it (`"phantom": "^0.7.2", "phantomjs": ">= 1.9 < 1.10"`).

Comment: But maybe I could find a way to don't have `Function.prototype.bind` called anywhere?

Comment: I think Garret may be right, try to include a polyfill in your Ember.js app like https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim or as an addon: https://github.com/pixelhandler/ember-cli-es5-shim, and then try to run it again. You can read up a bit on this here as well: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2634 which is a similiar issue

Comment: It might have help, because now I get a different error message:
 `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)`

Comment: Also this one: `Error: Could not find module ember-i18n/legacy-helper imported from foo/instance-initializers/ember-i18n`.